# Rails: respond_with custom object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, responders

respond_with is acatually meant to use with `ActiveModel`'s instances. I tried to use it with `OpenStruct`'s instance, but it raises an error.
Is that ever possible to use respond_with with custom objects?

```
class CryptController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def my_action
    respond_with OpenStruct.new(foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar')
  end
  # ...
end
```

Raises: **undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass**
ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:298:in`handle_list'
    /home/workstat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:206:in `polymorphic_method'
    /home/workstat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:114:in`polymorphic_url'

Comment: Can you show your code and error also first ? `respond_with` also works with AR objects.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`respond_with` is a helper method that exposes a resource to mime requests.

From the [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html)

```
 respond_with(@user)
```

for the `create` action, is equivalent (assuming `respond_to :xml` in the example) to:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
      format.xml { render xml: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.xml { render xml: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The precise equivalent is dependent upon the controller action.

The key takeaway is that `respond_with` takes a @instance variable as an argument and first attempts to redirect to the corresponding html view. Failing that, it renders an xml response, in the case above.

You are passing in an ostruct, which doesn't correspond to an instance of your model. In this case, `respond_with` doesn't know where to redirect to in your views and doesn't have an instance from which to render a mime response.

See this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3?autoplay=true) and [this blogpost](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/) from José Valim.

A note: The error `undefined method persisted?` is generated by Devise and probably because it can't find a route.